# How to use end="" snippet to create a bowling scoreboard

Tags: python

I am trying to create a python program that will read in a Bowling score composed of number of pins knocked out for each toss. I am trying to create an output that looks similar to a bowling scoreboard like this:

```
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9    10
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-----+
|8 /|7 2|9 /|X  |- 7|X  |- -|9 /|X  |X 9 /|
| 17| 26| 63| 70| 80| 80| --|100|129|  149|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-----+
```

I have the number of pins knocked down and the scores for each frame in two lists and will iterate through them 10 times to get the ten frames. I have tried different ways, but I am not having much luck. SO far I have something like this (assume that frame is accessing the right value in list).

```
for frame in range(1, 11):
    if frame <= 9:
        print("  {:d}  \n+---\n|    \n|{:d}\n+---".format(frame,frame),end="")
    else:
        print("  {:d}  \n+-----\n|    \n|{:d}\n+-----".format(frame,frame),end="")
```

Do you guys have any suggestions? Thank you so much!

Comment: You have *text*, please post that as such, and not as an image.

Comment: Just use a list of pin knockdowns, and calculate the scores from there. Also... have you done anything at all with the actual scores? All your code seems to handle is the frame numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've invoked `\n`, you can never go back and modify that line again. What you want to do is build 4 strings, and then print all in succession at the end:

```
def addEndCaps(lines):
    lines[1] += "+"
    lines[2] += "|"
    lines[3] += "|"
    lines[4] += "+"

lines = [ "", "", "", "", "" ]
for frame in range(1,11):
    lines[0] += "  %d " % frame
    lines[1] += "+---"
    lines[2] += "|   "
    lines[3] += "|   "
    lines[4] += "+---"

addEndCaps(lines)
print("\n".join(lines))
```

This produces output like this:

```
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10 
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Obviously you are going to have to do a bit of formatting logic to make sure the hyphens and spaces line up in the case of 2 and 3 digit numbers.

If you really have your heart set on using `end=""` (i.e. it's for a school assignment), then you'll have to create 5 `for` loops: one per line of output.